# ESLint available rules per ESLint version

Tags: eslint

Is there a way to get a list of available ESLint rules relative to an ESLint version?

For example, we're still on ESLint `v1.10.3` so I can't just assume that everything listed [here](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/) will be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We keep archived versions of the documentation around on the website, so the rules for `v1.10.3` are available at http://eslint.org/docs/1.10.3/rules/.

You can see what other versions are available in the [`eslint.github.io` repository](https://github.com/eslint/eslint.github.io/tree/master/docs).